# How to duplicate partition content?

Tags: oracle10g

I'm trying to set-up a testing environment for performance testing, currently we have a table with 8 million records and we want to duplicate this records for 30 days.

In other words:
- Table 1
--Partition1(8 million records)
--Partition2(0 records)
.
.
--Partition30(0 records)

Now I want to take the 8 million records in Partition1 and duplicate them across the rest of partitions, the only difference that they have is a column that contains a DATE. This column should vary 1 day in each copy.

Partition1(DATE)
Partition2(DATE+1)
Partition3(DATE+2)

And so on.

The last restrictions are that there are 2 indexes in the original table and they must be preserved in the copies and Oracle DB is 10g.

How can I duplicate this content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me to be as simple as running as efficient an insert as possible.

Probably if you cross-join the existing data to a list of integers, 1 .. 29, then you can generate the new dates you need.

```
with list_of_numbers as (
  select rownum day_add
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 29)
insert /*+ append */ into ...
select date_col + day_add, ...
from   ...,
       list_of_numbers;
```

You might want to set NOLOGGING on the table, since this is test data.